# Example of a particular group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Example of a non-cyclic group of order 111.

By sylow third theorem,I can say that when that group will be non-cyclic,it has 37 subgroups of order 3 and a subgroup of order 37

Answer (score 0):

$111=3\times 37$ and note that $3$ divides $37-1$. So a non abelian group of order $111$ exists. Explicitly, the standard one is $$\left\{\begin{pmatrix} x & y \\ 0&1 \end{pmatrix}: x \in H , y \in \Bbb Z_{37} \right\}$$ where $H$ is the subgroup of the multiplicative group $\Bbb Z_{37}^*$ of order $3$( such a group exists by Cauchy theorem)

This group is non abelian and hence non cyclic of order $111$